# How do I retrieve a Windows Store app's icon from a C# desktop app?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

In C#, getting an .exe file's icon is easy. You just do `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path)` and voilà.
But what if the app I want to get the icon of is not a standard .exe, but one of these newfangled Windows Store apps?

Is there a way to get the icon of a Windows Store app as a Bitmap object in my C# app?

Comment: So, you want to extract image from third-party app? Do you know where app is stored after deployment?

Answer (score 1):

In case of windows store UWP application you will have application icon path in form of so called "Indirect string".
For example for Groove music:

`@{Microsoft.ZuneMusic_10.18011.12711.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.ZuneMusic/Files/Assets/AppList.png}`

To extract normal path from indirect string [SHLoadIndirectString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb759919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) windows API function can be used.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

class IndirectString
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", BestFitMapping = false, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
    public static extern int SHLoadIndirectString(string pszSource, StringBuilder pszOutBuf, int cchOutBuf, IntPtr ppvReserved);

    public string ExtractNormalPath(string indirectString)
    {
        StringBuilder outBuff = new StringBuilder(1024);
        int result = SHLoadIndirectString(indirectString, outBuff, outBuff.Capacity, IntPtr.Zero);

        return outBuff.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you get the indirect string?

Comment: @Professorofprogramming We use GetIconLocation method of IAssocHandler interface

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered on superuser for general approach:
https://superuser.com/questions/478975/how-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut-to-a-windows-8-modern-ui-app

If you want to do it in C# - it partly depends on where you start. Do you want an icon for a specific app or icons for all apps? Do you know the path to the app, app name or app ID?

You can get a list of apps using a PowerShell `Get-AppxPackage` command. I haven't gone too far in getting it working, but to do that from C# you would install the `System.Management.Automation` NuGet package, then run something like this:

```
using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(InitialSessionState.CreateDefault()))
{
    runspace.Open();

    PowerShell powerShellCommand = PowerShell.Create();
    powerShellCommand.Runspace = runspace;
    powerShellCommand.AddScript("Get-AppxPackage |?{!$_.IsFramework}");

    foreach (var result in powerShellCommand.Invoke())
    {
        try
        {
            if (result.Properties.Match("Name").Count > 0 &&
                result.Properties.Match("InstallLocation").Count > 0)
            {
                var name = result.Properties["Name"].Value;
                var installLocation = result.Properties["InstallLocation"].Value;
                Console.WriteLine(installLocation.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    runspace.Close();
}
```

The problem with the above is that it returns a lot of component packages that are not actual apps. I could not find a simple way to find app display names either. You can crack open the AppxManifest.xml found in the install location, but for any localized app it will have something like "ms-resource:ApplicationTitleWithBranding" for its display name which seems complicated to extract from outside of the app.

To just get a list of apps from the registry you can use the `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` class to read the registry from "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Extensions\ContractId\Windows.Protocol\PackageId", then use the technique described on superuser to get the tile images.